# function pointer in a structure

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Suppose I have the following types:

```
typedef uint8 (*P2MyFunc)(void);

typedef struct
{
    P2MyFunc ptr;
}MyStruct;
```

Given an instance `inst` of `MyStruct`. is there any difference at all between the following calls ?

```
(*inst.ptr)();
inst.ptr();
```

Both seem to work just fine but the first one might be prone to compiler warnings.

Comment: Have you tried it? Is there a difference?

Comment: "might be prone" - Do you have any proof? Why do you suspect this?

Answer (score 0):

They mean the exact same thing according to the C Standard. You could even go a step further. The following below give the same result:

```
(********inst.ptr)();
inst.ptr();
```

Comment: Whenever you are referencing the C standard, it's nice to point the relevant paragraph...